Replay Chrome recorded flows is a loop
I have recorded a simple user flow interaction using Chrome's recorder tool. I would like to replay it in a loop. What's the simplest way to do that? I see Puppeteer as one of the export types. A command line tool to run the recording would be OK. I could loop it in a command prompt or power shell.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a
Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and explain the specific problem
with your code.
